# BUILD FAILED in 6s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build.gradle, flutter-android

**When I am trying to run my flutter app in Android emulator it throws this exception:**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/divyesh12/Documents/Development /GitRepos/Shopapp_flutter/myshop_app/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:23: AAPT: error: unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>.
```

flutter doctor result:

```css
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• No issues found!
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```cs
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myste_app">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

**Note: It works fine in iOS, how to fix this?**

Comment: The error is in your debug `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You can find it in `android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`. Please add it's content to the question.

Comment: I have added Manifest file content here. @Andrej

Answer (score 1):

You maybe adding the permission in the wrong xml file.

You should be editing the xml file in this path to add permissions:

```
\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```